# The use of trap as a verb?

Tags: verbs

A paragraph from a ACT English test:

[image]

For the underlining part, how should I understand the expression "trapping to". Honestly I've looked it up in the dictionary, but there ain't such expression as "trap to" .

Comment: I assume it means 'trapping the foxes in order to [put ear tags on them etc.].'

Comment: The writer has dropped a few words which is common in English.  Understand it as *if they see us trapping [the foxes] to put ear tags on [them] and change [the foxes' radio collar] batteries.*  An ACT English test used brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an example of a phrasal verb "trap to".  Instead, this is a usage of the verb [**trap**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trap) in its intransitive sense:

> 1: to engage in trapping animals (as for furs)

In this case, the context tells us that the animals the speaker is trapping (i.e., capturing) are kit foxes.

The phrase beginning with "to put on ear tags..." is an adverbial phrase modifying the verb "trapping".  It uses the preposition [**to**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to) according to this definition:

> 2a: —used as a function word to indicate purpose, intention, tendency, result, or end

It is common to use an adverbial phrase beginning with "to..." to describe the purpose of an action - you can understand it meaning the same as "in order to..."  For example:

> He's exercising to lose weight.

In your example, "putting on ear tags and changing radio collar batteries" is the purpose behind the trapping of the kit foxes.